# BlockBlob Download in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm currently trying out the Azure TableStorage and have a question regarding BlockBlobs:
Can I download specific BlobBlocks by their BlockID using REST (and how)?

I thought it could be something like: http://storagename.blob.core.windows.net/test/hello.zip?&blockid=001 , but this returns the whole file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I doubt this is possible, I could be wrong but the file only becomes an entity to be downloaded once you call `putBlockList` on the list of blocks to form a single entity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently it is not possible today but it sure is a good request.

You could do the following as an alternative:

1. Get the blocklist first
2. Calculate the offset (using the length associated with each block)
3. Issue a Range Get request for that offset/length

Answer (score 0):

You have to download Blocks by byte range. `Range` option must be set within HTTP Header (not in url query string).

Example:

```
GET /test/hello.zip HTTP/1.1
Range: bytes=0-102399
Host: storagename.blob.core.windows.net
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179440.aspx